# Docker and VirtualBox on Fedora 27

Tags: docker, virtualbox, fedora-27

I installed virtualbox 5.2 from their website. And I ran this command..

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
```

then I got this..

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is
"WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
available for the current kernel (4.14.3-300.fc27.x86_64) or it failed to
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\\n5.2.2r119230\". 
Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org"
```

I did as it suggested..

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

then..

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
kernel-devel kernel-devel-4.14.3-300.fc27.x86_64
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
kernel-devel kernel-devel-4.14.3-300.fc27.x86_64
```

..and I don't understand anymore. Please help.

Comment: Did u try `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`?

Comment: Nope. I did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the kernel-devel package and it will continue.  Btw, this is not a programming question, there are better forums for such questions...

Comment: Jeez.. this is why I came here last. I did, sir. I did. I did ask on #fedora, ask.fedora and r/fedora. But I haven't got answer from those yet. Thanks anyway.